# Change a number arithmetically in a text file using perl

Tags: perl, awk

I have a bunch of numbers in a text file as follows (example

```
r0           = 204
r1           = 205
max_gap      = 20u
min          = 0
max = 8
thickness    = 2
color        = green
fill_under   = yes
fill_color   = green
r0           = 205
r1           = 206
```

I would like to divide any line with r0           = by 100 so that the line will then read

```
r0           = 20.4
```

I would like to do this for all lines with r0 and also for r1. Is there a way to do this in perl?

This is my attempt but doesnt work mainly because I've never used perl before which is why I'm asking such a simple question

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string= r0\s+=\s+\\(d+)
$num= $1/100
$num2= r0\s+=\s+\\$num
s/$string/$num2;
```

A one liner I could run from bash would be much better though. I know it'll involve the s/find/replace function but not sure how to specify the integer part

Comment: Yes, you can do it in perl or awk pretty easily. Please show your attempt and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Code ammended. Please help

Comment: That doesn't even look like valid Perl syntax.

Comment: As explained perl never use before. Are you prepared to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 's{^r[01]\s*=\s*\K(\d+)$}{$1/10}e' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pei 's#^(r[01]\s*=\s*)(\d+)$#$1.$2/100#e' filename
```

The options mean:

- `-p` = Run the code in a loop that prints the modified input
- `-e` = Execute the code in the first argument
- `-i` = Replace the input file(s) with the output

The regular expression bits mean:

- `^` = beginning of line
- `r[01]` = `r0` or `r1`
- `\s*=\s*` = any amount of whitespace, an `=`, and any amount of whitespace
- `\d+` = digits
- `$` = end of line

The replacement uses the `e` modifier, which means that it should be executed as a Perl expression. `$1` and `$2` are the contents of the two capture groups: `$1` is everything before the number, `$2` is the number. `$2/100` divides the number by `100`, and `.` concatenates the two pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^r[01]/ {$3/=100} 1' file
r0 = 2.04
r1 = 2.05
max_gap      = 20u
min          = 0
max = 8
thickness    = 2
color        = green
fill_under   = yes
fill_color   = green
r0 = 2.05
r1 = 2.06
```